# Is calling setTimeout with a negative delay ok?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

The following snippet sets a timeout that I'd like to last at least a second:

```
var currentTimeMillis = new Date().getTime();
// do stuff...
var sleepTime = 1000 - (new Date().getTime() - currentTimeMillis);
```

Given that `sleepTime` can be a negative number, is it safe to call `setTimeout`, like this:

```
setTimeout(callback, sleepTime)
```

Or do I need to check for negative values before calling `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Specification) reference, the specification requires that there is a minimum timeout.

If you provide something less than this (HTML5 spec says 4ms) then the browser will just ignore your delay and use the minimum.

So negatives should be fine, since it'll just be less than the minimum.

---

Apparently, this isn't always the case (isn't that always the way with web development!). According to ( http://programming.aiham.net/tag/browser-compatibility/ ):

> Providing setTimeout a negative time will not always result in the
>   callback function being called. This works in other browsers, but in
>   Internet Explorer (8 or lower) you have to make sure any negative
>   times are changed to zero.

I haven't tested this myself, but like Thomasz said, it's probably better to be safe.

Comment: Screw IE8.  No timeout for u!

Comment: After testing on IE 8 using one of the VMs from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/, I can confirm that IE 8's `setTimeout` implementation does indeed never execute your function if you pass it a negative timeout. At least IE 8 is ancient enough now that *most* of us can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 74):

Better be safe than sorry:

```
setTimeout(callback, Math.max(sleepTime, 0))
```

Comment: Ah cool, for some reason I thought I must do `if (sleepTime > 0) setTimeout(...) else`, which would have been a bit uglier.

Comment: there's always `setTimeout(callback,sleepTime>0?sleepTime:0)`, if performance is an issue

Comment: This is a great solution. The problem with the other stuff is it makes the code look more complex than it is.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a conditional statement, like so:

```
if (sleepTime < 0) {
  sleepTime = 0;
}
setTimeout(callback, sleepTime);
```

Comment: Or use a ternary statement `setTimeout(callback, sleepTime > 0 ? sleepTime : 0)`

Comment: this is exactly the answer above this one.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... The solutions mentioned solves the problem at the call to `setTimeout`, so it needs to be written each time a call is made. Isn't it better to solve it directly in `setTimeout`?

```js
// Run this once.
(function(){
    var oldSetTimeout = setTimeout
    setTimeout = function(callback, delay){
        return oldSetTimeout(callback, Math.max(delay, 0))
    }
})()

// Call setTimeout safely with a negative delay.
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Hello World") }, -42)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is ok to use negative timeout in milli-seconds like this.

```
        setTimeout(() => {
        btn.style.top = '16.2%';
        btn.style.left = '35.8%';
        btn.style.transition = 'all 1.2s ease';
        },-1.2*1000);
```

This code will initiate **transition** on button of id btn after **1.2*1000** seconds of delay,**style top** and **style left**

Comment: The negative timeout is the same as a 0 timeout. Specifying -1.2*1000 is at best confusing the issue.